# jsPlumb not dragging lines to endpoints

Tags: jquery, jsplumb

I'm very new to jsPlumb and I'm trying to wrap my head around it.   Check out this link: http://thejohnkay.com/jsplumb.  When you drag and object from the left and drop it in the area in the right, I got it to where it creates the elements and their respective endpoints I just can't create lines to one another by dragging the anchors and it's driving me nuts.

the main file I'm dealing with is http://thejohnkay.com/jsplumb/js/main.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replicated your issue with this **[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpanga/uavrn7sk/)**

The only thing you should do is wrap your main.js script in dom-ready block

I did some corrections, below is the main.js

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";

    var jsPlumbMaster = function () {
        //function jsPlumbMaster(){
        if (typeof jsPlumb !== 'undefined') {
            this.countBox = 0;
            this.instance = jsPlumb.getInstance({
                // default drag options
                DragOptions: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    zIndex: 2000
                },
                // the overlays to decorate each connection with.  note that the label overlay uses a function to generate the label text; in this
                // case it returns the 'labelText' member that we set on each connection in the 'init' method below.
                ConnectionOverlays: [
                    ["Arrow", {
                        location: 1
                    }],
                    ["Label", {
                        location: 0.1,
                        id: "label",
                        cssClass: "aLabel"
                    }]
                ],
                Container: $(".drop-area")
            });
        }
    };

    jsPlumbMaster.prototype = {
        connectorPaintStyle: {
            lineWidth: 4,
            strokeStyle: "#61B7CF",
            joinstyle: "round",
            outlineColor: "white",
            outlineWidth: 2
        },
        // .. and this is the hover style.
        connectorHoverStyle: {
            lineWidth: 4,
            strokeStyle: "#216477",
            outlineWidth: 2,
            outlineColor: "white"
        },
        endpointHoverStyle: {
            fillStyle: "#216477",
            strokeStyle: "#216477"
        },
        // the definition of source endpoints (the small blue ones)
        sourceEndpoint: {
            endpoint: "Dot",
            paintStyle: {
                strokeStyle: "#7AB02C",
                fillStyle: "transparent",
                radius: 7,
                lineWidth: 3
            },
            isSource: true,
            connector: ["Flowchart", {
                stub: [40, 60],
                gap: 10,
                cornerRadius: 5,
                alwaysRespectStubs: true
            }],
            connectorStyle: this.connectorPaintStyle,
            hoverPaintStyle: this.endpointHoverStyle,
            connectorHoverStyle: this.connectorHoverStyle,
            dragOptions: {},
            overlays: [
                ["Label", {
                    location: [0.5, 1.5],
                    label: "Drag",
                    cssClass: "endpointSourceLabel"
                }]
            ]
        },
        // the definition of target endpoints (will appear when the user drags a connection)
        targetEndpoint: {
            endpoint: "Dot",
            paintStyle: {
                fillStyle: "#7AB02C",
                radius: 11
            },
            hoverPaintStyle: this.endpointHoverStyle,
            maxConnections: -1,
            dropOptions: {
                hoverClass: "hover",
                activeClass: "active"
            },
            isTarget: true,
            overlays: [
                ["Label", {
                    location: [0.5, -0.5],
                    label: "Drop",
                    cssClass: "endpointTargetLabel"
                }]
            ]
        },
        init: function (connection) {
            connection.getOverlay("label").setLabel(connection.sourceId.substring(15) + "-" + connection.targetId.substring(15));
            connection.bind("editCompleted", function (o) {
                if (typeof console != "undefined") console.log("connection edited. path is now ", o.path);
            });
        },
        addToStage: function (top, left, label) {
            //var top  = parseInt(moveQueue[0][0]);
            //var left = parseInt(moveQueue[0][1]);

            $('<div>', {
                'class': 'window',
                    'id': ('flowchart' + this.countBox)
            })
                .css({
                left: left,
                top: top,
                position: 'absolute'
            })
                .text(label)
                .appendTo($('.drop-area'));
            //console.log(this.instance)
            this._addEndpoints($('#flowchart' + this.countBox), ["LeftMiddle", "BottomCenter"], ["TopCenter", "RightMiddle"]);
            this.countBox++;


            this.instance.draggable($(".drop-area .window"), {
                grid: [20, 20],
                containment: 'body'
            });

        },
        _addEndpoints: function (toId, sourceAnchors, targetAnchors) {
            for (var i = 0; i < sourceAnchors.length; i++) {
                var sourceUUID = toId + sourceAnchors[i];
                console.log(sourceUUID);
                this.instance.addEndpoint(toId, this.sourceEndpoint, {
                    anchor: sourceAnchors[i],
                    uuid: sourceUUID
                });
            }
            for (var j = 0; j < targetAnchors.length; j++) {
                var targetUUID = toId + targetAnchors[j];
                this.instance.addEndpoint(toId, this.targetEndpoint, {
                    anchor: targetAnchors[j],
                    uuid: targetUUID
                });
            }
        }
    };


    var JPM = new jsPlumbMaster();

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.panel').draggable({
            containment: 'body',
            stop: function (e, ui) {
                var top = parseInt($(this).css('top'), 10) + 250;
                var left = parseInt($(this).css('left'), 10);
                var label = $(this).text();
                if (left >= parseInt($('#left-col').width(), 10)) {
                    $(this).remove();
                    left = left - 250;
                    JPM.addToStage(top, left, label);
                }
            }
        });

        $('#box').keyup(function () {
            var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            $('.filter .panel .category').each(function () {
                var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                if (text.indexOf(valThis) > -1) $(this).closest('.panel').fadeIn('fast');
                else $(this).closest('.panel').fadeOut('fast');
            });
        });
    }).foundation();

});
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that was all I had to do. I wonder why it needs it wrapped in a dom ready function.  Thanks a million!